# How to group items inside foreach based on multiple if conditions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want looping my `form-group` inside `form-horizontal` using `foreach` from knockout. I have condition when `Id` is 1 and 2, this should be grouped inside `<fieldset>`. I already tried when just 1 condition is working normally, but when multiple 1 and 2 it's not working.

Code Sample:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" data-bind="foreach: forArray()">
<!-- ko if: Id() === 1 -->
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        Foo
    </legend>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: Id() === 1 || Id() === 2 -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-5"><span data-bind="html: NameColumn"></span></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Id" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: Id() === 2 -->
</fieldset>
<br />
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: Id() !== 1 && Id() !== 2 -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-5"><span data-bind="html: NameColumn"></span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Id" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your *containerless control flow syntax* won't work. You should treat them as if they are real html container element like you would with a `<div>` tag.

From the [documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-without-a-container-element):

> The `<!-- ko -->` and `<!-- /ko -->` comments act as start/end markers, defining a “virtual element” that contains the markup inside. Knockout understands this virtual element syntax and binds as if you had a real container element.

Even if you fix your syntax, it won't display your desired output. A single looping through `forArray` can't create this functionality, because it will create more than one `fieldset` element for both `Id` 1 and 2. So, you need to create a [`computed`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) property. This computed property will have 2 array properties:

- `lessThanTwo`: push the items with `Id`s 1 and 2
- `moreThanTwo`: push the items with `Id` greater than 2

Every time the original `forArray` changes, `groupedArray` gets computed again. You can test this by changing the `Id` input of `Ronaldo` to 5. That item will get moved outside of the `fieldset`.

Use the [`with`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) binding to create a new [binding context](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) in `form-horizontal` div

```js
const viewModel = function() {
  const self = this;

  self.forArray = ko.observableArray([
  { NameColumn: '<u>Messi</u>', Id: ko.observable(1) },
  { NameColumn: '<b>Ronaldo</b>', Id: ko.observable(2) },
  { NameColumn: '<i>Griezmann</i>', Id: ko.observable(3) },
  { NameColumn: '<u>Mbappé</u>', Id: ko.observable(4) }
  ]);

  self.groupedArray = ko.computed(() => {
    const groupedObject = {
      lessThanTwo: [],
      moreThanTwo: []
    };

    self.forArray().forEach(item => {
      // if Id() > 2 push it a moreThanTwo property
      // otherwise push it to lessThanTwo property
      if (item.Id() == 1 || item.Id() == 2)
        groupedObject.lessThanTwo.push(item);
      else
        groupedObject.moreThanTwo.push(item);
    })

    return groupedObject;
  })
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="form-horizontal" data-bind="with: groupedArray">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      Foo
    </legend>
    <!-- ko foreach: lessThanTwo -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-5"><span data-bind="html: NameColumn"></span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Id" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

  </fieldset>
  <br />
 <!-- ko foreach: moreThanTwo -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-5"><span data-bind="html: NameColumn"></span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: Id" />
    </div>
  </div>
 <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a little mess with ko-/ko tag pairs

Form what you rote `<fieldset>` will be opened if condition `Id() === 1` is valid but will be closed if `Id() === 2`

Comment: yes will be opened in `Id() === 1` and be closed in  `Id() === 2`. But not working. What I must do @LoidGaba

Comment: Yes.. That's what I want.